# Past Perfect or Perfect Tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I have some questions regarding past perfect tense, as I am still quite confused about the usage.

Which one of the below is correct?

> 1. The books that her parents **got** her had not made her an intellectual person.
> 2. The books that her parents **had got** her did not make her an intellectual person.

And also the below:

> 1. As the problems between John and I evolved, I **had started** to develop symptoms of depression.
> 2. As the problems between John and I evolved, I **started** to develop symptoms of depression.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first pair of examples, both the following are correct, because there is consistency.

> 1a) "The books that her parents **had got** her **had not made** her
>   an intellectual person."

And ..

> 2a) "The books that her parents **got** her **did not make** her an
>   intellectual person."

Regarding the second pair of examples, I would rewrite them as follows.

> 1b) "As the problems between John and I **evolved**, I **started** to develop
>   symptoms of Depression."

And...

> 2b) "As the problems between John and I **had evolved**, I **had started** to develop symptoms of Depression."

Comment: You should explain tense agreement in your answer.